# FutureBuilder keeps Firing the Future method

Tags: flutter, httprequest, mobile-development, flutter-futurebuilder

I get the data from http request, then i load it using futureBuilder, the problem is that it keeps calling the future method even if i set a variable with the future method in 'initState ()', but it still keeps calling it multiple times, i also tried the AsyncMemoizer too but no good, here is the code:
[my FutureBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb9Vp.jpg)

[future method and iniState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZtCj.jpg)

[Http request method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNQmJ.jpg)

[home screen build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Q7b.jpg)

I hope someone help me with the solution.

here is the rest of the code:

[launcher screen build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS9oe.jpg)

[connection method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls7Zr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Futurebuilder widget depends on future. As, you haven't shown your build method I can't predict surely. But, I think You have called **mainWidget()** Future from your Build method. So, whenever you're build method gets re-rendered or called Your **mainWidget()** also get called and so does your **FutureBuilder** Widget and its future.

So, you will need to make sure that your **mainWidget()** does not gets called many times. Or manage your build widget in a way that your **FutureBuilder** doesn't need to be called more than once.

To check simply add a print log in your **mainWidget()** that it is called multiple time or not.

This will solve your issue I think.

Comment: thank you, yeah the build function was called multiple times causing the same behavior for other widgets, i will try to fix that .

Comment: i still cant figure the problem, i call this screen from a launcher one that check connection but i don't know why it call the home screen multiple times, i added the missing code.

Comment: @KaneDavid If you add print logs for all your methods or debug each point of execution will help you to figure out why your "Build" method or "mainWidget()" is being called multiple times.